# Is it possible to setup (install apps, adjust settings, etc) an MDM Mac, with an "admin" user, then change the user to a "standard" one?

Tags: macos, applications, apple-id, administrator, apple-business

I'm sorry if the language in the title is confusing. I struggled to type out what I'm trying to do in one sentence. Hopefully I can provide some context below that will help.

1. My company buys Mac devices from an Apple Reseller so the devices we get are registered to our MDM automatically
2. In order to sign into this device to begin setup, I have to create an Apple ID from Apple Business Manager (ABM)
3. Which then prompts me for a phone number and I enter my own
4. I proceed to install apps, adjust settings, and move apps around for end user
5. Once done, I have to change the phone number on the Apple ID I created from ABM, which involves me reaching out to end user to get the code texted to them to complete the process

I want to avoid step 5 essentially. Is there a way for me to do all the other steps and just change the user I login as to the end user's Apple ID I generate and act as it's the first time they're logging in so I don't need to contact the user to change phone numbers and they'll have all the apps and settings that I adjusted before when they login?

I know a Device Plan will help with some apps getting pushed when the end user logs in but we have custom apps that need to be installed, with additional commands that need to be executed, and settings adjusted for those specific apps.

Please let me know if any further info is needed or if this question is answered elsewhere.

Thanks

Comment: To update this: I've had to reformat several Mac Minis today and after I reset the phone number in ABM, it didn't require me to go through the whole process. It just told me the next time the user signs in, they'll be asked to change it. So maybe my problem is "solved"? Last time, ABM popped up a phone number change window and I had to enter the new number. I'd still be interested to know if there's a better way to do what I'm doing though...